# Locking a user using a per-user `maximum_attempts` value with Devise for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

As a de-facto standard, we all using Devise for login in our Rails application and will use the Lockable module to lock users after a particular number of failed attempts.

From Devise’s [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L129) and the configuration option `config.maximum_attempts = 20`, I came to understand how Devise performs locking when the user tries to give wrong login credentials. Configuration is statically defined at Rails application boot time in `initializers`.

My expectation is to set the `maximum_attempts` dynamically – is this possible? If so, please guide me.

I have a superadmin and user below each admin. Based on the super admin I would like to set a different `failed_attempt` value for each user during runtime.

Comment: For each user? Why do you want such behavior? What if you get 1.000s of users? Do you want to manage all of them individually?

Comment: Yes @TheCha͢mp , Superadmin1 may have 1000 user and for all of those 1000 user the failed_login_attempt should be ex:3, super admin2 may have 5 as failed_login_attempt...

Comment: it seems like a lot of work for very little gain... Why not set globally? I guess it's up to you...

Comment: yes @TheCha͢mp , client requirement is like that.  if you can help me please point in the right direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to monkey-patch the Devise code that [you linked to](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/ac702843ddaa5652fde7a0050ff2378e7368149e/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L129), where `attempts_exceeded?` is defined. Here’s a guess at what needs to be overridden:

```rb
module Devise::Models::Lockable
  # assumes that the User model has a `superadmin` relation
  #  that has a `maximum_attempts` attribute

  def attempts_exceeded?        
    self.failed_attempts >= self.superadmin.maximum_attempts
  end

  def last_attempt?
    self.failed_attempts == self.superadmin.maximum_attempts - 1
  end
end
```

This should work, but it would mean that whenever you update Devise, there is a risk of related code breaking, with unknown consequences. So you would have to review the changes to Devise before every update. And if you are discouraged from updating Devise because of this, that may eventually cause security problems if you are too slow to update to a version of Devise with a fixed security problem. So beware of those possible problems.

A safer way that requires more work up-front is to lock the user manually from your own code. The documentation for `Devise::Models::Lockable` mentions a public method [`lock_access!`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Lockable#lock_access%21-instance_method) that locks the user when you call it. You can set the global `config.maximum_attempts` to some really high value such as 25. Then, in some callback on the model (I’m not sure which callback), call a method `lock_access_based_on_superadmin_limit!` that calls `lock_access!` if necessary according to your custom rules. The following definition is adapted from [part of Devise’s `valid_for_authentication?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/ac702843ddaa5652fde7a0050ff2378e7368149e/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb#L104-L105):

```rb
class User
  # …

  def lock_access_based_on_superadmin_limit!
    if failed_attempts >= superadmin.maximum_attempts
      lock_access! unless access_locked?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @rory-okane Thanks for the brief explanation. I also thought the first attempt and FULLY agree on the problem with monkey patching... Thanks again

Comment: How to handle the number devise shows like x attepts remaining, or if we have enabled config.last_attempt_warning = true in devise config, how would we handle this?

Comment: @FerdinandRosario did you get this working to your satisfaction? I'm working on the same thing and trying to figure out where such a callback should be done.

Comment: @CChandler81yeah I followed the above .... Ferdy_Rosario is my twitter handle plese get in touch with me for any help...

Comment: @FerdinandRosario I think CChandler81 is asking about this part from my answer: “in some callback on the [User] model (I’m not sure which callback), call … `lock_access_based_on_superadmin_limit!`”. Which callback did you use in your solution?